# How to throw an error in gulpfile?

Tags: gulp, watchify

I have started using watchify in my gulp build recently, but i don't understand, why it doesn't throw an errors in terminal, when something is wrong. Probably, i should add something like `if(err) throw err` somewhere, but i don't understand where exactly.

Also, this code suppose to do kind of hot reload, but it doesn't, it just building much faster than without watchify, but it reloads page anyway.

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
    var bundler = browserify({
        entries: ['src/js/main.js'], // Only need initial file, browserify finds the deps
        transform: [babelify], // We want to convert JSX to normal javascript
        debug: true, // Gives us sourcemapping
        cache: {}, packageCache: {}, fullPaths: true // Requirement of watchify
    });
    var watcher  = watchify(bundler);

    return watcher
    .on('update', function () { // When any files update
        var updateStart = Date.now();
        console.log('Updating!');
        watcher.bundle() // Create new bundle that uses the cache for high performance
        .pipe(source('main.js'))
    // This is where you add uglifying etc.
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
        console.log('Updated!', (Date.now() - updateStart) + 'ms');
    })
    .bundle() // Create the initial bundle when starting the task
    .pipe(source('main.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```